# Replacing a part of some string with variable if both values will change dynamically - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace

I've got another difficult problem to solve with JavaScript. The string variable comes from outside form input value as you can see below

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Country = document.getElementById('countr').value;
}, false);
```

The string address which I need to change is a part of relative href address and will take two different forms.

models/world/some_site.html

or

models/local/some_site.html

The variable Country will be changing as well for example: German, England, France etc.

If I want to replace 'world' or 'local' with Country variable what I need to do is doing something like that

```
var address = address.split('world').join(Country).split('local').join(Country);
```

or

```
var address = address.replace('world', new RegExp(Country, 'g')).replace('local', new RegExp(Country, 'g'));
```

The result should be look for example like that

models/German/some_site.html

But it doesn't work I don't know why. Any help will be very precious for me.

I discovered that my Country variable don't want to be processed, why?
This script not display my variable at all.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var Country = document.getElementById('cotr').value;
}, false);

document.write(Country);
```

So this example don't working as well

```
address.replace(/(local|world)/,Country)
```

Any help?

My real code looks as below

```
Indeks.prototype.wyswietl = function(adres)
{
if (typeof adres == 'undefined') adres = 
document.forms[this.id].elements['hasla'].value;
if (typeof this.ramka == 'string')
{
var okno = 
window.open(adres, this.ramka, 'menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
if (okno) okno.focus();
else window.location.href = adres;
}
else this.ramka.location.href = 
adres.replace(/(world|local)/,Country);//here I need replacement adres is address
}
```

Comment: can you give example input and output?

Answer (score 1):

you want to replace the middlepart of text `models/local/some_site.html` with Counry variable.

you can use `split()` function to split the string based on `/`.
after getting the splitted strings you can take `index[1]` value as it contains country value `local` or `world` to be replaced.

and then you can use `replace()` function for replacing the text.

**Sample Code as below:**

```
    <script language="javascript">
    var address="models/local/some_site.html";
    var Country="france";//Example
    var finaladdress=address.replace(address.split("/")[1],Country);    
    </script>
```

**Complete Solution :**

**Code1:** Declare your `Country` variable as `global`

```
var Country;//declare the Country outside the function so it becomes global
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
Country = document.getElementById('countr').value;
}, false);
```

**Code2:** Do `replacement` here

```
Indeks.prototype.wyswietl = function(adres)
{
if (typeof adres == 'undefined') adres = 
document.forms[this.id].elements['hasla'].value;
if (typeof this.ramka == 'string')
{
var okno = 
window.open(adres, this.ramka, 'menubar=yes,toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
if (okno) okno.focus();
else window.location.href = adres;
}
else this.ramka.location.href = 
adres.replace(adres.split("/")[1]),document.getElementById('countr').value); // here I need replacement
}
```

Comment: or a regex for the replacement... like `address.replace(/(local|world)/,Country)`

Comment: but we don't know the middle part right , sometimes it can be other than (local or world).please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: i have edited my answer with section "solution asper your code" please check that and let me know.

Comment: address variable means in your code it is 'adres' right? in that case it available for replacement function right?

Comment: That's right adres in my code is address appearing later and the `var Country = document.getElementById('countr').value;` is in the beginning of the code.

Comment: please check my edited answer with section Complete Solution , it works perfectly now.

Comment: After making corrections Country value became undefined, why? Ooo It's terrible.

Comment: add alert(Country); after stmt-> Country = document.getElementById('countr').value;  in 1st block of code and check wether it is printing any value or not.

Comment: Yes it is printing right value in alert but the variable is not passed on beyond the function. despite its declaration is a global

Comment: can u print that variable outside the function?

Comment: No outside the function it's printing undefined.

Comment: why do you need to depend on variable Country just get the value of Country that is -> document.getElementById('countr').value directly in 2nd block of code right :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `join()` is used for arrays and leaves commas in the resulting string, so you should use `concat()` instead. Second, `replace()` would be a much simpler solution, like so:

```
var regex = /(world|local)/;
address.replace(regex,Country);
```

EDIT:

I've tested my code, so the method itself works. The problem in that case must be in your `Country` variable. Are you sure its scope is global? The way it appears in that of yours function suggests it isn't visible anywhere outside the event listener. Or perhaps you can link the event listener directly to the rest of your code and pass it as a function argument if you consider globals to be evil.

Comment: This example not working because my Country variable don't want to be processed. See my edited asked question.

Comment: How to do it I mean link the event listener directly to the rest of the code.

Comment: By the looks of it `Indeks` is supposed to be a constructor object, so the simplest option here appears to be the use of a global.